# Is there a way to blur a zone of an image with javascript or Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to blur a zone of an image with javascript or Jquery ?

Thanks

Comment: If it's for the visual representation, I'd just lay a translucent image over it. But I guess you want to modify the original image? Then I'd strongly suggest doing this server-side, e.g. via PHP. If you do it in JavaScript, any user could still get the original image, if he wants to.

Answer (score 1):

There is a jQuery plugin that does this, if jQuery is an option?

[Image Blur with jQuery](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/image-blur-jquery-effect)

[Blurring an image in HTML 5](http://www.flother.com/blog/2010/image-blur-html5-canvas/)

Answer (score 0):

No.

The only thing you can do is use another image on top.

Comment: It looks like the jquery plugin does that: http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.blurimage.js_1.txt (adds multiple transparent versions on top, to blur)